# Intellij HotSwap complex application in websphere

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere, hotswap

I have really complex application containing a lot of modules like:

parent.ear

-child1.war

--child2.war

-child3.jar

--child4.jar

---child5.jar

Each parent got child in depedencies. I have each as seperate module. If I want to make change in jar and switch with new jar for example child5.jar I need to use mvn install in this order:

1. child5.jar
2. child4.jar
3. child3.jar
4. parent.ear

Is there any chance to hot swap classes/resources on Websphere (using ctrl+F10) only child5.jar? When I compile child5.jar into target and use hotswap function (Update classes and resources) it doesn't see any changes on server.

Target in module looks like:

Target

-child5-1.0-SNAPSHOT(folder)

--....a lot of compiled folders and classes

--...

--...

-child5-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

I don't want to use JRebel.

I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: doesnt work for me for single ear single war as well